# Sending Emails via Swiftmailer in Yii2 won't work on external Server

Tags: php, email, yii2, smtp, swiftmailer

I am using Swiftmailer in Yii2 advanced and everything, this includes sending emails, works fine on my xampp server. But when I try it on my external Server (1&1 btw) I get a

> Swift_TransportException
>       Connection could not be established with host
>         smtp.1und1.de [Connection timed out #110]

I already googled about it for hours an tried almost every solution including using gmail instead or using ports 465 and 25 with ssl and tls. Also using IP-Adress instead of hostname.

I feel like there could be a firewall or some email options I miss but I have tried everything I can think of.

My code looks like this:

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',

                'host' => 'smtp.1und1.de',
                'username' => 'mymail@myadress.de',
                'password' => 'mypassword',
                'port' => '587',
                'encryption' => 'tls',
            ],
        ],
```

and again, works perfectly fine on localhost.
Maybe someone has an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: could be your server don't allow the use for this mail server .. but force yourself to use his  email server .. in this case you must assign  the related  configuration

Comment: I think you were right. Got it now by deleting all the 'transport' and letting swiftmailer do it's magic...